# Second nvidia is not recognised

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have msi CX61 2QF
    intel core i7
    intel hd graphics
    NVIDIA GeForce 940m
    Ubuntu 14.04

I want to install cuda 7.0, But when I install it (using .run file in tty1 mode - this is how I installed in my desktop) ubuntu is not working. I later tried to install nvidia driver only. I face the same problem. And then I checked for available vga using "lspci | grep VGA" command. It showed only one result

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

Please help me

Comment: @Pilot6, that's for you ;)

Comment: Are the two graphics cards bridged?

Comment: No, I don't know, how to find out